# Log-concavity of the growth function

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Given a Cayley graph of a group $G$ with finite generating set $A$ and exponential growth. Let $S_n$ be the elements whose word length is exactly $n$.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Is $f(n) = |S_{2n}|$ a log-concave function? i.e. $f(n)^2 \geq f(n+1)f(n-1)$.

Positive answer for all groups is possibly out of reach, so any extra hypothesis is welcome...

$\textbf{Motivation 1:}$ There are a few groups where the growth series is rational, so one can get a lot of numerical data. The above holds up to $n \geq 10^5$. In fact, in almost all cases [exceptions are described below], even $n \mapsto |S_n|$ is log-concave except for a few small $n$ (i.e. up to three values $\leq 15$).

I also tried a few linear groups and some semi-direct products (those that are easy to feed to a computer) and the same holds (except it can get hard to the values of $|S_n|$ for $n \geq 15$).

It could very well be that a counter-example has non-soluble word problem, so let me put a more precise version of the question for groups with rational growth function:

$\textbf{Question (restricted):}$ Is there a group with rational growth series so that there are 3 or more roots (of the same multiplicity) on the circle of convergence of the serie?

Indeed, for such groups, 3 or more roots seems to be a necessary condition for a negative answer to the question.

$\textbf{Motivation 2:}$ As a comparison, if $g(n)$ is the probability that a simple random walker returns to its initial point in $n$ steps. Then $g(n+1)/g(n)$ will never converge in bipartite graphs (in fact, there will be division by $0$). However, $n \mapsto -\ln g(2n)$ is concave.

[EDIT: The reason  for the $-\ln $ and why this could have anything to do with growth is the following observation. 
Let $P_n$ be the distribution of a simple random walk starting at then identity after $n$ steps. 
Let $\| F\|_p^p = \sum_{g \in \mathrm{Supp} F} |F(g)|^p$. 
Let $\Phi_p(n):= \frac{\ln \| P_n\|^p_p}{ (1-p)}$. 
Then $\Phi_2(n) = \Phi_\infty(2n) = - \ln g(2n)$. 
Also, defining $\Phi_1 = \lim_{p \to 1} \Phi_p$, one has that $\Phi_1(n) = h(P_n)$ (the entropy of $P_n$).
Lastly $\Phi_0(n) \in [ \ln |B_n|- \ln 2, \ln |B_n| ]$ (where $B_n$ is the ball of radius $n$). 
It turns out, $\Phi_1(n)$, $\Phi_2(n)$ and $\Phi_\infty(2n)$ are concave. So this also brings the question: how far is $\Phi_0(n)$ to be concave?..]

$\textbf{Motivation 3:}$ If one looks at self-avoiding walks in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ (say $c_n$ is the number of SA-walks of length $n$) then $c_{2n+2}/c_{2n}$ converges to $L^2$ (where $L = \lim c_n^{1/n} = \inf c_n^{1/n}$. If those self-avoiding walks could encode the geodesics of some group (lamplighter?), then it might support the fact that $|S_{2n+2}|/|S_{2n}|$ converges for these groups. [I don't think it is known whether $n \mapsto c_{2n}$ is log-concave or not.]

$\textbf{Important examples:}$ A [family of] example[s] due to Machi show that $|S_{n+1}|/|S_n|$ need not converge (these are the only examples I know where $n \mapsto |S_n|$ is not log-concave). These examples are given by free products $G_1 *G_2$ with $A = G_1 \setminus \{e_{G_1} \} \cup G_2 \setminus \{e_{G_2}\}$ (where $|G_1| \neq |G_2|$ and both are finite).
In this example (like in the random walk), a bipartiteness phenomenon causes the trouble, but can one find a group where some sort "tri-partiteness" in $|S_n|$ happens?

$\textbf{Question (variations):}$ Let $\lim |S_{n}|^{1/n} = \ell$. Is it true that $\inf_n |S_{2n+2}|/|S_{2n}| \geq \ell^2$? that $\lim_n |S_{2n+2}|/|S_{2n}| = \ell^2$? Can one always find a $k$ so that $n \mapsto |S_{kn}|$ is log-concave? has ratio test converging to $\ell^k$?

This question is related to

[On the size of balls in Cayley graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36126/on-the-size-of-balls-in-cayley-graphs/36132#36132)

[Folner sequences of amenable groups of exponential growth](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43964/folner-sequences-of-amenable-groups-of-exponential-growth)

and [Folner sets and balls](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148995/folner-sets-and-balls)

Comment: Have you considered non-residually finite examples?  For instance, Higman's famous fp group with no non-trivial finite quotients?

Comment: The above "seems" true in some Baumslag-Solitar groups (including (2,3) and (3,5) ) as well as some semi-direct products. I'm not terribly good at writing programs, so it would take me some time to see what happens to Higman's group.

Comment: small precision: for BS groups, "seem" = up to radius 18 for (2,3) and up to radius 15 for (3,5). There is a Master's thesis of Thomas Wong with a table for sphere in those groups up to that radius. For the solvable (and residually finite) case, one can compute (and check) more easily. But this is just numerical data. If you have a reference on how to compute growth of Higman's group, I'll be happy to look it up... The growth of non-residually finite BS groups is unknown, as far as I know.

Comment: A question: In motivation 2, don't you mean $n\mapsto g(2n)$ is log- *convex* ? The sequence $g(2n)$ should be completely monotone, which implies log-convexity.

Comment: oh right, sorry. I always think of $-\ln g$ and I forgot the minus sign... I'll edit this, and add a comment there...

Comment: @Antoine Thank you very much for the explanations. I never realized that that $-\ln g(2n)$ was exactly the 2nd order Rényi entropy after $n$ steps. This indeed implies that Rényi entropies of order 1,2 are concave. I wonder what the largest alpha is so that $\Phi_\alpha(n)$ is still concave. Continued

Comment: @Antoine I understand now that your conjecture is that 0th order Rényi entropy (aka Hartley entropy) is "almost" concave. This seems like a very powerful assertion. Let me check few examples on $\mathbb F_2^n$. I am assuming that concavity of Shannon entropy is standard, but could you either point me to an argument or very briefly sketch it? Thanks

Comment: @MertSaglam thanks, I did not know it was called Rényi entropy. The paper for the concavity is Kaimanovich & Vershik, Random Walks on Discrete Groups: Boundary and Entropy, Ann. Prob. 11(3):457-490, 1983. Link: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2243645 . It's equation (11) on page 464.