# Groups whose exponential growth is never pinched

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

This question is motivated by a [partial answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148995/folner-sets-and-balls/235348#235348) to another question on MO.

Given an infinite finitely generated group $G$ and a finite generating set $S$, let $b_n^S$ be the cardinality of the  ball of radius $n$ [around the identity].

Say a pair $G$ has pinched exponential growth w.r.t. $S$ if there are constants $K<L \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ so that $K 
\cdot \mathrm{exp}(Mn) \leq b_n^S \leq L \cdot \mathrm{exp}(Mn).$

**Question:** What are examples of amenable groups $G$ which have exponential growth, but there is no choice of generating set $S$, so that the group has pinched exponential growth (w.r.t. $S$)?

**Remarks**:

- the question could be strengthened to require that the group does not have a rational growth series. (If there are more than one pole on the radius of convergence of the growth series, then the group does not have pinched exponential growth.)
- the question could also be strengthened to require that the group be finitely presented.
- an equivalent formulation of the question is: let $g(S) =\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{b_n^S}$. Is there an $S$ so that $\limsup_n \dfrac{ b_n^S}{g(S)^n} < \infty$?

[EDIT: Further remarks:

- there would be a weaker form of the question where non-amenable groups could be considered. Non-amenable groups are however not interesting in this context (see linked question and comment below)
- [complement to a comment below] If $S$ is a generating set, let $S' = S \cup \lbrace e \rbrace$. Assume $G$ has pinched exponential growth w.r.t. $S_G$ and $H$ has pinched growth w.r.t. to $S_H$. Consider the generating sets $S_+ = (S_G \times \lbrace e_H \rbrace) \cup (\lbrace e_G \rbrace \times S_H)$ and $S_\times = S_G' \times S_H'$. Then it's not too difficult to check that $G \times H$ has pinched growth w.r.t. $S_\times$ (because the balls are just product of the balls). It does not have however pinched growth w.r.t. $S_+$. (To see this note that the balls have the form $\cup_{i =0}^n \sigma_i(G) \times \sigma_{n-i}(H)$ where $\sigma_i$ are the sphere of radius $i$. Combined with the fact that the sphere are also pinched [see linked answer for details] gives the fact that the growth is not pinched)
- [Still extension of that comment] Assume $G$ has pinched growth w.r.t. to $S_G$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}$ with $S_H = \lbrace 1;-1 \rbrace$ as generating. Then $G \times H$ has pinched growth w.r.t. $S_+$ but not w.r.t. $S_\times$. Indeed, the spheres w.r.t. $S_+$ have cardinality of the balls in $G$. So the cardinality of the balls w.r.t. $S_+$ can be bounded by geometric sums. On the other hand the balls w.r.t. $S_\times$ have the cardinality of a ball in $\mathbb{Z}$ times a ball in $G$ (i.e. bounded above and below by some function of the form $n exp(Mn)$). Hence not pinched. The case of $G=F_2$ is particularly easy to check (see comment below).
- If $G$ has pinched growth, then $G \times \mathbb{Z}^2$ does not have pinched growth w.r.t. to either $S_\times$ or $S_+$. But that does not exclude another generating set with pinched growth.
- Most "classical" amenable groups of exponential growth have a generating set with pinched growth (this includes the lamplighter group, solvable Baumslag-Solitar groups and metabelian polycyclic groups).

END of EDIT]

Comment: Is there a particular reason to assume amenability?

Comment: Every group of exponential growth has "pinched" growth.

Comment: @dodd what do you have in mind? the classical thing is that $(b_n^S)^{1/n}$ converges.

Comment: @Ycor it's natural in the context of the linked question ("it never happens that balls in a group of exponential growth are a Folner sequence"). If it were so that amenable groups of exponential growth always have a generating set with pinched exponential growth, then one would at least have that for some generating set, balls are not Folner. I seriously doubt this is the case however...

Comment: @dodd that's clearly false. Look at the group $G = F_2 \times \mathbb{Z}$ where $F_2$ is the free group with the "product" generating set $\lbrace (a,0), (b,0), (a,1), (b,1),(e,1) \rbrace$ where $a,b \in F_2$ are a free generating set and $e \in F_2$ is the identity. Then a ball of radius in $G$ is made of a ball of radius $n$ in $F_2$ times a ball of radius $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. The cardinality is consequently $2 \cdot 3^n -1$ times $2n+1$. But $b_n =  2(2n +1)(3^n-1)$ is not pinched growth.

Comment: @dodd I forgot to mention inverses in my generating set above... it should be $\lbrace (a,0), (a^{-1},0) , (b,0), (b^{-1},0) , (a,1), (a^{-1},1) , (b,1), (b^{-1},1), (a,-1), (a^{-1},-1) , (b,-1), (b^{-1},-1)\rbrace$

Comment: The ball w.r.t. $S$ and $S\cup S^{-1}\cup\{1\}$ are the same, so it was fine (and easier to read).

Comment: Do you really say that all metabelian polycyclic groups of exponential growth have some generating subset with pinched exponential growth? This would include groups of the form $\mathbf{Z}^2\times(\mathbf{Z}\ltimes\mathbf{Z}^2)$.

Comment: @Ycor you are right, I have written this last comment too hastily! Actually I was thinking of the groups like $\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}^n$. If there was a relatively simple way to compute the growth series of these groups, then a group like $\mathbb{Z}^2 \times (\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}^n)$ would be the first case to test.

Comment: @ARG but the example I gave is precisely of the form $\mathbf{Z}\ltimes\mathbf{Z}^4$. (You seem to write $\rtimes$ for $\ltimes$. The standard convention is [quotient]$\ltimes$[normal].)

Comment: @YCor apologies again... I think the growth is only pinched if  the matrix (which defines the action of the $\mathbb{Z}$ part on $\mathbb{Z}^n$) has no eigenvalue of norm 1. Otherwise, I have no idea how to show pinched growth. Except for the case where one takes a direct product with $\mathbb{Z}$. [And please also apologise: I almost always mix up $\rtimes$ and $\ltimes$]